# would a clock at Absolute zero have no mass

Tags: relativity

since Absolute zero corresponds to the theoretical state in which particles have no energy at all.

and m = E/c^2

Then would an unwound clock have zero mass if it was cooled ,theoretically , to Absolute zero

Comment: *"since Absolute zero corresponds to the theoretical state in which particles have no energy at all."*...what.

Comment: Just to keep @ACuriousMind from becoming personally unwound, I will attempt an answer. Hopefully, it's along the right lines.

Comment: Well done that man.

Answer (score 2):

> Absolute zero corresponds to the theoretical state in which particles have no energy at all.

Absolute zero is the point where where all molecules have no **kinetic energy**. It is a theoretical value (it has never been reached).

I think you are mixing up total energy with kinetic energy, (and ignoring rest energy)  then using E = mc$^2$ to conclude that no mass exists either.

A clock, wound or unwound,  would still have mass at any low temperature.

Ironically, it is at extremely high temperatures that it would have less mass, which would  convert to energy.

A particle will not "freeze" at absolute zero. This is because it will violate the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, which states that we cannot know the position and momentum of a particle simultaneously. At 0 K, it will simply be at its lowest energy state

Comment: Just to add some thermodynamics: It (from the point of a perfectly fine working theory) cannot be reached by any process.